# how to update html value without unique id in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I am developing a site that guides coin market arbitrage information.

I wonder if the way below is possible in JavaScript.(not React)

backend - django

```
def index(request):
    data = [{"name": "BTC", "binance": "price1", "gecko": "price2", "ftx": "price3"}, 
            {"name": "ETH", "binance": "price1", "gecko": "price2", "ftx": "price3"}]
       
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'data': data})
```

html -

```
<table class="table table-striped mb-0 fixed">
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>binance</th>
              <th>gecko</th>
              <th>ftx</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {% for d in data %}
              <tr>
                  <td>{{ d.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ d.binance }}</td>
                  <td>{{ d.ftx }}</td>
                  <td>{{ d.okx }}</td>
              </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
</table>
```

JS -

```
var socket = new WebSocket(
    'ws://' + window.location.host +
    '/ws?session_key=${sessionKey}')

socket.onmessage = function (e) {
    let positions_data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    
    //if positions_data {"site": "binance", "price": "27000", "name": "BTC"}
    //update data -> 
    data = [{"name": "BTC", "binance": "27000", "gecko": "price2", "ftx": "price3"}, 
            {"name": "ETH", "binance": "price1", "gecko": "price2", "ftx": "price3"}]

    //do something?
    //then change html value



    }
```

Is it possible to change the html value just by changing the variable in JS

Or is it possible to take additional code? Or is there another way?

Comment: [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), optionally with [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Why not add an ID to the `<tr>` that indicates which type of coin it is?

Comment: @barmar thanks, I was wondering if it is possible to change the HTML value simply by changing the variable in JS. (Instead of changing the html value through an identifier)

Comment: You can loop through the rows, looking for the one with the coin type in the first column, then update the appropriate other column. But adding attributes is much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML so that the rows have a unique ID based on the coin name, and the columns have classes that indicate their roles.

```
<table class="table table-striped mb-0 fixed">
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>binance</th>
              <th>gecko</th>
              <th>ftx</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {% for d in data %}
              <tr id="row-{{d.name}}">
                  <td class="name">{{ d.name }}</td>
                  <td class="binance">{{ d.binance }}</td>
                  <td class="ftx">{{ d.ftx }}</td>
                  <td class="okx">{{ d.okx }}</td>
              </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can find the row that corresponds to `positions_data` and update it:

```
let row = document.querySelector(`#row-${positions_data.name}`);
let site = positions_data.site;
row.querySelector(`.${site}`).innerText = positions_data.price;
```